# Where are the worlds in many-worlds interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, universe, quantum-interpretations

What does it mean in [MWI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) for other universes to exist? Are they in some sector of spacetime beyond our cosmic horizon or is it more complicated?

I'm not asking this on Philosophy SE because people on there are generally not as acknowledged in physics/mathematics as here and the crucial part of the answer is a good knowledge of MWI itself.

Comment: The other worlds are not at other point in (regular) space, but at other points in Hilbert space, where the states of quantum mechanics live.

Comment: More precisely, they are points in the state space of the Universe, which is presumably a (projectivization of) some particular Hilbert space.

Comment: A great book on this topic is by Hawking and Penrose titled The Nature of Space and Time.

Comment: Any interpretation of the MWI that posits that other universes exist as real physical objects falls apart at the seams because of the existence of a classical regime. Interpretations that make these other universes some sort of mathematical construct are basically a copout to avoid admitting that MWI simply doesn't explain anything. The correct explanation for the Born rule can be found trough an analysis of the measurement process.

Answer (score 3):

In nonrelativistic quantum mechanics the wavefunction is defined on configuration space.

So for $n$ particles there is a $3n$ dimensional configuration space. And the quantum wavefunction is a function from $\mathbb R^{3n}$ into the complex numbers (or into a joint spin state if you have spin).

There could be regions where the wave is zero or very small, and others where it is comparatively large. Now let's look at what happens when a so called measurement occurs, as an example we will do a Stern-Gerlach device meeting a spin 1/2 particle.

The particle comes in going in the $+\hat y$ direction, say along the $y$ axis. The particle will have some width in the $\pm\hat x$ direction and as it travels in the $+\hat y$ it will widen and split and form two branches, much like the capital letter Y. So over time it starts out having he wavefunction be nonzero near the a horizontal line by the bottom then advances to become nonzero in a horizontal line a bit farther. Like a line of traffic approaching a fork in the road. These are the places in configuration space where the wavefunction is nonzero.

And it really is in configuration space. The wavefunction is not some field in space and time. This means the configuration has many directions $$(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2,\dots x_n,y_n,z_n)$$ and one of them the $y_k$ that corresponds to the $k$-th particle's position along the $y$ axis so the wavefunction could be zero for all configurations except some of the ones there is a range of $y_k$ and a range of $x_k$ that form a part of that Y.

So what happens is waves split. Much like a water wave could break against a rock and become two waves. But this is not yet two worlds. These waves could meet some other rocks (say, some Stern-Gerlach devices oriented in different directions) and end up overlapping. So the waves can still know about the other one.

But the configuration space is large and they can interact with different things. If the left branch had the $x_k$ get close to a $x_i$ for a different particle (and their $y$s and $z$s are close) they could interact. If you draw the wave so you see the nonzero values for that other particle say as having the z axis be $x_i$ then you might see the left branch go up. And similarly the right branch might go up where up is related to the $x_J$ of an even different particle. So it is much like a series of space ships in a thousand dimensional space and making little detours when a location in the large space means two particles are close
 Eventually the two branches have wiggled into slightly different places in the configuration space to the point where it would be hopeless to have them ever cross each again. Either on purpose or on accident.

So it is like you had a single cells organism that divided and then the new cells went off in different direction in a space that was as big as $\mathbb R^{10^{80}}$ and they will just not meet again. These waves that now interact with themselves but not each other. They are the worlds. They are called worlds because they only care about themselves.

Yes, originally it was just a split and they weren't yet different worlds. But there is no moment they became different worlds. It just became practical for each wave to think of itself as the only wave.

**So wavefunctions are functions from a very huge dimensional space into the complex numbers, and there is room in there for waves that describe our universe and that as they evolve forward in time, they never interfere with each other.** These are the worlds, and they all live in the same place. If you ran them backwards they would interfere, but you don't.

Comment: Configuration space is an abstract mathematical construct, it's not physical reality (not even in classical scenarios or statistical mechanics). We don't assign physical meaning to such constructs. Why would the MWI, especially since none of these "splitting waves" has any physical meaning?

Comment: @CuriousOne The question asked where, so I wrote a geometric answer. Any world doesn't live in a different place than the individual world you are subjectively familiar with. You personally don't notice things that don't affect you even indirectly and are incapable of affecting you, even indirectly. So it isn't strange to call your world those things that can effect you. It's as relevant as distinguishing between your proper past in GR and everything else. The reason you group a collection of configurations together and call them a world is because a world is the thing you do science with.

Comment: Here is the problem with that argument: You haven't made any position measurement on any of these other worlds, so how can you tell where they live? Sorry, friend, but this is horribly bad science. No, it's not science, at all, because there is no empirical way to test a hypothesis like that. Please don't give the OPs the wrong impression of what physics does. Physics does not count angels on pins.

Comment: @CuriousOne Its the minimum you need to do science and its the part that is subjectively falsifiable. It's really the exact thing you are aiming for. Each split wave is literally the result you get from, say, a so called "measurement" interaction, well the time evolution of the split wave is what you get.

Comment: @CuriousOne The position measurement is exactly when then two branches start to wiggle into different region of configuration space until they have wiggled differently into so many different dimensions in configuration space that they can't overlap.

Comment: That's the whole point: you can't test MWI. You can't measure these "split waves". Indeed, they don't exist. We know what the measurement process does and it's not wave splitting into other universes. You are simply transferring the unknown state of your measurement apparatus on an unknown outcome of the measurement. That is a physical explanation for the very thing that MWI can't explain, at all.

Comment: Configuration space is a mathematical construct. It does not exist outside of the paper its written on. You can't do measurements in it.

Comment: @CuriousOne As for telling where they live, you yourself are made a part of the system being described. If your brain is going to make you go left or right based on whether your left/right eye interacts with the rest of the world in particular way then that is included in the configuration space so you end up going left or right based on your eyes. Your brain functioning differently is the predicted result, there isn't a cartoon version of yourself waiting to see a wave in configuration space.The support of the wavefunction includes the possible onfigurations of your brain and body

Comment: That's another one of those delusions of pseudo-science, that the human brain is somehow involved in physical processes. You are a very smart guy, but you really need to go into the lab and do a measurement to experience that your brain has absolutely nothing to do with spins pointing up or down. Your main problem, I believe (and that's where Everett went completely wrong, too) is that you simply don't know what the crucial requirement for an observation is and why that impacts the result without any need for a human observer or even an experiment!

Comment: @CuriousOne "*You are simply transferring the unknown state of your measurement apparatus on an unknown outcome of the measurement.*" that is exactly what MWI explains and predicts. In Stern-Gerlach you have an indeterminate position in the x direction (lots of configurations with nonzero values). That indeterminate result becomes correlated to the newly modified spin, and it does that because the position is then easier to have the split get promoted to distinct worlds from roughly thermodynamic reasons.

Comment: The crucial detail of the measurement process isn't part of MWI, so how can it predict its outcome? The quantum states in Stern-Gerlach are reduced to completely classical trajectories by the macroscopic size of the magnetic field, already, long before the actual detection happens. The only question that I have there is why the quantum mystics don't know that?

Comment: @CuriousOne When you talk about that brain nonsense I truly can't tell if you are trying to understand things I say if you are so sure that other researchers must be idiots and therefore your misconceptions about other fields have to be right. The split happens before they are different worlds, the different worlds happen before and even without brains, but I brought up brains because you used language that made it sound like you needed us to get to brains before you know what is going on. The Schrödinger equation predicts splits and worlds and is consistent with observations.

Comment: Only pseudo-science brings the human brain into the discussion whenever it is out of a scientific argument. It's not in any physics textbook that I would take seriously. Can you even hear yourself talk? You are talking about unmeasurable entities as if they exist. That is not science. Science is the explanation of measured entities. All you have to explain as a physicist is the spectrum of the hydrogen atom. You don't have to count the number of invisible ghost atoms needed to make that spectrum.

Comment: Let's go back to basics. What is the one fundamental property of a measurement? Answer me that.

Comment: @CuriousOne As for the magnetic field: finally, some science. I agree that external classical vector potentials are merely the easiest way to describe the setup and my point was merely to bring up an early stage split that happen before there are different worlds. The proper place to put that split is exactly where it is still possible to get interference between splits of wavefunctions that aren't yet separate worlds because the number of independent degrees of freedom required to get meaningful quantum type interference hasn't been reached yet.

Comment: You are still talking about angels. At least I am glad that you admit that 99% of the analyses of Stern-Gerlach by the quantum mystic crowd are 100% wrong. Now all you have to do is to join the 1% that actually understand Stern-Gerlach for what it is, an experiment that is, at all stages, in a semiclassical regime. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne I brought up brains because you said "*Here is the problem with that argument: You haven't made any position measurement on any of these other worlds, so how can you tell where they live?*" and I couldn't tell if you were bringing brains up, and I couldn't tell that partly because it seemed at the time like you wanted to misunderstand and misrepresent. And so it was hard to tell what you level or end you were trying to talk about, I apologize for thinking you were bringing it up. But I don't **even** know how you could think I was assigning causal properties when it happens latter.

Comment: I didn't bring brains up. I never bring brains up. They are completely useless to do physics. :-) Your assignment for tomorrow is to count the number of photons in the magnetic field that a typical spin in a typical Stern-Gerlach experiment interacts with. :-) You also owe me an answer to the question what the one crucial characteristic of a physical measurement is. You know that one, don't you?

Comment: A definite value @CuriousOne :)

Comment: @Timaeus I know that this was over 4 years ago, but I am writing in the hopes that you respond, since this was probably the clearest explanation of MWI that I've seen. My main confusion is how we are supposed to imagine the entire universe in which we live. If all of these things that are happening in configuration space are real, then where are they? Is our own physical universe also "huge dimensional"?

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean in MWI for other universes to exist? Are they in some sector of spacetime beyond our cosmic horizon or is it more complicated?

The other universes are not in some other place. Rather, physical reality as a whole is the multiverse, a structure that in some approximations looks a bit like a collection of parallel universes, but also has [much richer structure](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033). A universe is a structure within the multiverse in which information has been copied. For example, the version of me that is typing this sentence is in the same universe as you because you are able to read this particular version of the sentence. There is some other version of me that has typed a slightly different version of the sentence and there is some other version of you reading that sentence. There is nothing more to being in the same universe than having information about a particular value of some measurable quantity. There is no space external to the whole multiverse where you could say "Oh, the universe in which Alan typed the word chocolate as the tenth word in this sentence is three feet to the left of the universe in which he typed the word "panda" as the tenth word in this sentence." Rather, those universes are different universes because of that difference in the tenth word of that sentence (and other stuff, like differences in my brain that resulted in me typing chocolate instead of panda).

Answer (score -3):

As a quantum theorist, this area of physics perfectly intersects my area of knowledge. A simple Google search can lead you to my favourite site for philosophical inquiry.

> The Many-Worlds Interpretation (MWI) of quantum mechanics holds that there are many worlds which exist in parallel at the same space and time as our own. The existence of the other worlds makes it possible to remove randomness and action at a distance from quantum theory and thus from all physics.

[Source: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-manyworlds/]

If this is not of assistance, maybe I can help.

For every decision you make, and that will ever be made, there exists a universe for every possible outcome. These universes exist until the decision has been made. Then all other universes collapse. There now exists only one universe where you made the one decision and that is the universe you live in. If it makes sense, the universes of the many-worlds interpretations exists in our space-time until the decisions have been made. Then the other universes collapse and cease to exist. I hope this helps and please comment with your thoughts.

Comment: This in NOT what the many-worlds interpretation says. Nothing collapses, only different parts of the wavefunction decouple from eachother.