# What are fundamental reasons for conservation laws in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, superposition, decoherence

Let me be a little silly and suppose that when "God" created our Universe - he had these 3 options:

1. (Most classical): let the energy (contained in any particle = field excitation) **spread evenly** among all points of it's wave function (like probability *actually* does; interference included) and **without collapse**.

There's a rule, ruling out that option, which states (quoting loosely) that quanta can not be changed (split\created\destroyed) without interaction with another; and I guess I'm fine with that explanation.

2. (Least classical): let the energy be **infinitely copied** at each point of it's spreading wave function and **without collapse**.

This would gave us Many Worlds, except with a single World.

3. (Many Worlds - as I currently see it): same as 2, but **it collapses** ("branches", "decohere") each time different wave functions intersect.

The Question is: what are exact reason(s) why we observe some sort of 3, instead of 2 - ?..

I didn't include option for Copenhagen because I don't feel like it can provide any insight (sorry, fandom!..); I also added tags referring to QFT and it's fandom for the opposite reason.

Comment: How 'fundamental' are symmetries as in [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @Nihar Karve - I can't say; does it proofs infinite copying of energy wrong as in options 2 or 3? One could argue that energy is constant in ALL three options, but in 2 and 3 it's infinite and simply becomes available in different locations via spreading.

Comment: I just wish there was explanation for wave function collapse as simple and satisfying as one that rules out option 1.

Comment: **Okay, this one helped:** https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/208161/246877